# How to prevent different users to edit same record using JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, session

Please help me in this, I have a JAVA application and i am using oracle as backend. My problem is i am showing a list of records with unique ids, i need to prevent different users to edit the same record. i am totally blank about this requirement please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: search the answer, this is a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into `DBMS_LOCK` 
[Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lock.htm#ARPLS021)

Edit: this has nothing to do with Java. You need a direct lock on your database table. A programming language won't help.